# How to have a condition within a [disabled] attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to have a condition within a condition for a `[disabled]` attribute?

This is my attempt at what I'm trying to do for a button:

`[disabled]="(second.checkoutHasSupplies() || !second.confirmed) && (!second.confirmedPickUp || !confirmed)"`

I want the button to be disabled:

1. if `second.confirmedPickUp` is not confirmed
2. if `confirmed` is not confirmed
3. and then **only if** `second.checkoutHasSupplies()` is true, **then** if `second.confirmed` is not confirmed

I can get numbers 1 and 2 in the list above working, but I can't seem to figure out how to do number 3. As you can see in my code above, I tried `(second.checkoutHasSupples() || !second.confirmed)`, but that's not working.

Also I'm sure it's clear, but just to clarify, I have the `second.` in front of some of the code because I'm pulling the data from another component. However the string that's just `!confirmed` is within this component I'm trying to do this on.

I'm really not sure how to achieve this. Any step-by-step walkthroughs would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
[disabled]="(second.checkoutHasSupplies() && !second.confirmed) || !second.confirmedPickUp || !confirmed"
```

But maybe your second.checkoutHasSupplies() function returns false when the component is mounted... is there an Ajax call in this function ?
You should replace second.checkoutHasSupplies() by a variable like "hasSupplies" and set it to "true" by default, or false, and then update this "hasSupplies" variable when second.checkoutHasSupplies() returns a different value.

Answer (score 0):

So as Benjamin stated before me, you want your condition to be `[disabled]="(second.checkoutHasSupplies() && !second.confirmed) || !second.confirmedPickUp || !confirmed"`

However, you should know - it is very bad practice to have a function call in the HTML from a performance point of view - since this is something that will have to run to re-evaluate every time.

If your function is pure, a better solution than calling a function is calling a pipe.
If your function is impure, it is better to bind the HTML to a property and have the function call and update the property a different way than binding straight to your HTML